# nested layouts in laravel emails

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am working with a part of my application that sends out emails the moment, I want the emails to use a base layout (branding etc) and then an individual template loaded in within that, that is specific to the email type, I know that you can do layouts in views like this when using a controller and view,

`protected $layout = 'layouts.master';`

however I cannot find a suitable way to use this when sending an email like this,

```
Mail::send('emails.organisations.admin_removed', $array, function($message) use ($array) {
    $message->to("email@email.com", "Simon Ainley")
        ->from('sender@email.com', 'Email Sender')
        ->subject("Email Sender - Subject");
});
```

Is it possible to have a master email template and then feed in sub views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah! this is possible.

**Your main template** (emails.orgainsations.template_layout.blade.php)

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <meta name="author" content=""/>

    <title>{{config('app.project_name')}}</title> 
    <style>
       //your css goes here

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="wrap">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="header">
                    <h1 class="logo" title="Logo"><img src="{{ asset('assets/images/logo-mail.png') }}" alt="logo" /></h1>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 20px; border: 1px solid #8a35e1; color: #323232;">
                    @yield('content')

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

**Your child template** (emails.organisations.admin_removed)

```
   @extends('emails.orgainsations.template_layout')
   @section('content')
   <p>
      your mail content goes here
   </p>
   @endsection
```

And, in mail sending code, call the child template as usual

```
  Mail::send('emails.organisations.admin_removed', $array,   function($message) use ($array) {
$message->to("email@email.com", "Simon Ainley")
    ->from('sender@email.com', 'Email Sender')
    ->subject("Email Sender - Subject");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create a master blade template and the extension is done in the child blade templates. Then you pass the child template to your `Mail::send()` method.

So you have your master: **emails/layouts/master.blade.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Email Master</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        Dear {{ $recipient }}

        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>

        Kind regards,

        @include('emails/signature')
    </body>
</html>
```

Then extend in the child template: **emails/layouts/organisations/admin/remove.blade.php**

```
@extends('emails.layouts.master')

@section('content')
    <p>You have been removed</p>
@endsection
```

Then pass the child view to the send method:

```
Mail::send('emails.layouts.organisations.admin.remove', $array, function($message) use ($array) {
    $message->to("email@email.com", "Simon Ainley")
        ->from('sender@email.com', 'Email Sender')
        ->subject("Email Sender - Subject");
});
```

I've glossed over a lot of details here so I highly recommend checking out the docs for further in-depth details: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade

You should also try to familiarise yourself with all the different directives blade offers to take full advantage of all its features.